# Linux shell: web-safe variant of a binary RSA signature of base64

Tags: linux, shell, openssl, base64, digital-signature

In Linux, I have a file 'signature.bin' with a binary RSA signature, and I would like to get a web-safe variant of it of base64.

How can I do it with the shell?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `base64` command in the GNU Coreutils. So simply

```
base64 signature.bin
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `base64` is not web-safe for many web applications. You need to use a tool such as `base64url`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

Comment: Yes, I was searching a command to convert to a URL-safe string. But "base64url" is not installed on my server. I must first "base64" and then use a URL-encoder.

Comment: @Hookstark.  Check out https://base64.guru/standards/base64url/encode